# Cached Variables in VSTO Office 2010

Tags: vsto, office-interop

After having a look around the web, I have found the following posts (below) which are quite similar to my problem. However, after trying the solutions, I am still stuck.

[VSTO Frustration](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsto/thread/227f3974-9585-463c-8209-6438ba81b0bd)

[Setting cached variables in VSTO 3.0](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsto/thread/204f7747-f121-42da-8442-9bd036c457dd/)

Basically, I want to populate some data in a Excel file on a web server before I send it to the client.

Here is my code in the Workbook:

```cs
namespace Inno.Data.Excel
{
  public partial class ThisWorkbook    
  {     
     [Cached]        
     public DataSet Config = new DataSet();     

     private void ThisWorkbook_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
     {
         //InitializeCachedData();          
         var baseUrl = (string)Config.Tables["Config"].Rows[0].ItemArray[0];            
         var streamIds = (string)Config.Tables["Config"].Rows[0].ItemArray[1];

         MessageBox.Show(baseUrl + " " + streamIds);
     }
  }
}
```

and on the server side I have the following:

```ml
let rootUrl = Uri(x.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority))

let setUpData (report : Report) (sd : ServerDocument) =
    let url = rootUrl.AbsoluteUri
    let streamIds = String.Join(",", report.series |> Seq.map(fun s -> s.id))

    let dt = new System.Data.DataTable("Config")
    dt.Columns.Add("BaseUrl", typeof<String>) |> ignore
    dt.Columns.Add("StreamIds", typeof<String>) |> ignore
    dt.Rows.Add([|box url; box streamIds|]) |> ignore
    dt.AcceptChanges()

    let cache = sd.CachedData.HostItems.["Inno.Data.Excel.ThisWorkbook"]
    let urlItem = cache.CachedData.["Config"]
    urlItem.SerializeDataInstance(dt)
    sd.Save()
    sd.Close()

let initialiseDocument (report : Report) (path : string) =
    let fileName = report.name.Replace(" ", "_") + ".xlsx"
    let sd = (new ServerDocument(path)) 
    sd |> setUpData report 
    fileName

let docPath = x.Request.MapPath(Path.Combine(liveReportPath, "Inno.Data.Excel.xlsx"))
let fileName = initialiseDocument report docPath
x.File(File.OpenRead(docPath), "application/vnd.ms-excel", fileName) :> ActionResult
```

However, when I go to open the file after it has downloaded, I get the following error:

```
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Runtime.CannotFindObjectToFillException:    Cannot find any public instance member with ID Config in object Inno.Data.Excel.ThisWorkbook.
```

Things I have tried:-

- Using a simple string rather than a DataSet
- Calling `StartCaching("Config")`
- Manipulating the `ServerDocument` in memory using the `byte[]` file overload
- Copying the original Excel file and operating on the copy

But now I'm out of ideas. I see that a fair number of people have had this error, and as is pointed out in [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsto/thread/204f7747-f121-42da-8442-9bd036c457dd/), there was a known bug in VSTO 3.0 with manipulating files in memory.

Thanks in advance.